# Colouring the text on the video

Tags: html, wordpress

I am using the Listify theme and I want to change the colour of the text on homepage video. Below is my code in which I have video and text

```
[video width="1280" height="720" mp4="http://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/abcd.mp4" loop="true" autoplay="true" preload="auto" webm="http://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/abcd.webm"][/video]

<span style="color: #ffffff;">Thinking Good, Living Good!</span>
```

Problem is that the text that is apearing above the video is the HTML code - "Thinking Good, Living Good!" rather than the text "Thinking Good, Living Good!" in White Colour.

Comment: What is the url so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

The only text elements in HomePage Video from the preview theme page are the following:

```
<h1 class="home-widget-title">Search Your City</h1>
<h2 class="home-widget-description">Listify helps you find out whats happening in your city, Let's explore.</h2>
```

Both are in white text and you need to find the following code in the file `style.min.css` or `style.css` and change the color value to whatever you want.

```
.homepage-cover.has-image .home-widget-title {
    color: #fff;
}

.homepage-cover.has-image .home-widget-description {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Unfortunately, the information you provide in your question cannot give us the opportunity to help you more. It's like shooting in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('video').next('span').removeAttr("style");
})
```

For remove default style:

Ex: color:#fff;